# Strange Resolution Line Ubuntu 16.10

Tags: graphics, 16.10

I'm using Ubuntu 16.10 in a Dell Inspiron 5537 with i5-4200U and Integrated Graphics Haswell Mobile. When i watch a video or move some webpage up or down at the browser, or even changing workspaces, the screen shows a resolution line, sometimes in diagonal. Someone is having the same issue? It was working fine in 16.04. Please forgive my gramatical mistakes, english is not my main language.

Comment: I've had problems with horizontal lines before watching videos and vertical lines when scrolling in Chrome, but never diagonal lines. Are you sure `diagonal` is the right English word?

Comment: Yes, its really a diagonal line, it only show up when scrolling web pages and changing workspaces, and it goes only until the middle of the screen then it becomes horizontal. That is why is so strange. When watching videos, only a horizontal line appears. I think it could be related to Intel drivers.

Comment: @Malkon yes I had the similar problem of the horizontal line for a long time but don't know exactly what I did to fix it because I did many things at once. Check out this answer I wrote but note to use Kernel 4.8.1 instead of 4.7.3: http://askubuntu.com/questions/827939/ubuntu-15-10-various-types-of-freezes-and-now-unexpected-shutdown

Comment: @Malkon Let me know if any of it works and I"ll take that answer and migrate it over here because the original question has been closed and other people won't look at it.

Comment: Ok @WinEunuuchs2Unix Ill do that.

Comment: Hi @WinEunuuchs2Unix! I forgot to come back, i'm sorry, but the tips didnt worked for me. I'm waiting that a miracle update, fix it. Thank you!

Comment: No worries about being gone a fortnight. What browser are you using?